# Is there a fastest way to count object repetitions in an array than a HashTable?

Tags: c++, optimization, hashtable, repeat

I'll try to be as clear as I can. I have already implemented my solution and it works, I just need to know if it would be best to use other data structure instead of a Hash table

It's a college question, but I already submitted to the teacher and it works, I just wanted to see if anyone would have done it differently.

So, this is the problem:

Given an image ( PPM 3,all the data stored as ASCII in RGB )
e.g.

```
P3
# The P3 means colors are in ASCII, then 3 columns and 2 rows,
# then 255 for max color, then RGB triplets
3 2
255
255   0   0     0 255   0     0   0 255
255 255   0   255 255 255     0   0   0
```

I need to divide each pixel by a constant given wich will be power of two ( 2,4,8…………64,128)

```
c= 32;
Pixel2(255/c,255/c,255/c) = Pixel2(7,7,7)
```

Then, I need to convert all the pixels to patches of a given width,and the patch will accumulate the RGB values of the pixels it contains

e.g.

```
w=3;   imageW = 10; imageH=10;
Patch[0].r = Pixel[0].r + Pixel[1].r + Pixel[2].r +
             Pixel[10].r + Pixel[11].r + Pixel[12].r +
             Pixel[20].r + Pixel[21].r + Pixel[22].r;
Patch[0].g = Same for g component;
Patch[0].b = Same for b component;

Patch[1].r = Pixel[1].r + Pixel[2].r + Pixel[3].r +
             Pixel[11].r + Pixel[12].r + Pixel[13].r +
             Pixel[21].r + Pixel[22].r + Pixel[23].r;
etc…
```

Then, I need to count the number of repetitions of each patch in the image.
So, What I've done it's I have the Image class, which reads the image from a file (ifstream), and a Pixel class, which has the r,g,b and nAparations components. I read the pixels, divide them by tha constant given, and get the patches acumulating the values of it's containing pixels.

After this We have a data vector in my Image class wich it's an array of Patches Objects
e.g.

```
data = [Patch0{r comp,g comp, b comp, 1 parition}, Patch1{r comp,g comp, b comp, 1 parition} …..];
```

Now, What I've done it's using a hash table, insert each Patch, if it's already inserted, just update it's nAppearances component, if not, insert it.
After all are inserted, return a vector with all the elements in the hash table.
This vector, will only have one ocurrence of each Patch, and it's nAppearances component will cointain tha number of times each Patch appears in the image.

Is there any other way? Or a hash table is the best approach?

Also, what kind of hash function would you use? Currently I'm using

```
hash = patch.r * 1 + patch.g *2 + patch.b*3;
tableSize = maximun number of patches (assuming no one repeats)
insert into table[hash%tableSize];
```

The Hash table allows collision, each position in the table has a list of elements.

Sorry if it's to large, just wanted to be clear. Also sorry if my English isn't good enough!
thanks.

Comment: Well, I am one of the lectures of this subject and the organizer of the programming contest that this student is participating. Feel free to help him, but it is suppose that the students have to solve the contest by their own, or just reading different programming sources but not using an active query to the community.

Anyway as i have detected this queries, any other participant can, and the copy is completely forbidden........

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2 things

**first: If you are going to hash colors:**

If R, G and B are colors from 00 to FF the simplest thing is to just create a hash function that is 24-bit i.e. RRGGBB then mod it by some prime number that is the size of your hash table. What size is your hash-table? Is it a prime number?

For example 65536 would be a very poor choice of hash-table size. 65539 would be fine.

unsigned int colornum( unsigned int red, unsigned int green, unsigned int blue )
{
   return (red << 16 | green << 8 | blue);
}

then hash is just `colornum(r,g,b) % hashTableSize;`

**alternatives to hash:**
Use std::set with the RGB 24-bit number, or with the rgb numbers but the compare using the 24-bit number. That way you can count the number of duplicates. It is not as fast as hash though.

By the way, if you can afford it, 2^24 is only 16M and if you used a bitset that would use 2MB. You could run through all your colors setting the "flag" for each color that occurs then count duplicates that way.

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering. The things is it had to work with a set of images quite big(we don't know the actual number) and with images of differents sizes (15x15,..,120x120,..,1024x1024..). Your approach for the hash function was what I had thought, but I didn't knew how to implement it (mostly because I didn't think of the logic OR function…).Having different sizes of images, I wasn't using a fixed tableSize,rather the maximum number of patches posible for each image. As I see, would it had been better to use a high prime then? (just a bit lower than a power of 2 number).

Comment: Well, after a bit of testing, implementing that hash function result in a 30 times faster hash table when inserting 1 million keys(Patches). Just Wow, really. I've been looking and there are a lot of "famously fast" hash functions (MurmurHash,FNV,SuperFastHash,Dense-hash by google..) that I might try, although they seem to be faster for strings keys.

Answer (score 0):

using @CashCow hash function I've gained quite a bit speed.

unsigned int colornum( unsigned int red, unsigned int green, unsigned int blue ) { return (red << 16 | green << 8 | blue); }

then hash is just colornum(r,g,b) % hashTableSize;

The thing is, I need to do the calculation of the number of repetitions of patches for a lot of images, (One at-a-time), and they can vary a lot (one might have only 81 patches, 10x10 image, other might be 1024x1024 with up to +1million patches if all are differents..)

So I'm having problems adapting the hashTableSize for this operation ( colornum(r,g,b) % hashTableSize) in each image, because a big number for a very small image won't be optimal, and the contrary would cause A LOT of collisions…
I've also looked into other famously fast hash functions like murmurhash2 but I don't know how to properly implemen them. (Do I still need to do % hashtableSize to the unsigned int they return?? Because if It's a yes then I don't think they should be faster than @CashCow sugestion, as I'm doing A LOT less operations)

If it's of any indication, just after this, I'll need to retrieve the array of patches and sort it(because I'll need to compare them and find the differences, and as far as I know, the fastest way to compare two array of objects It's first having them sorted right??) so If you know any method that would calculate fast the number of repetitions, and also let me later retrieve it already sorted say it.

I'm thinking a balanced tree might do the trick, It's asymptotically worst both the lookup and the insertion, but I'd get rid of the problem for radically different sizes of images and also I would be able to retrieve them sorted by trasversal Inorder(don't know it thats the name of it in english..).
Any thoughts on this would be appreciate ir. Thanks again!